# iPad QR scanner - how to adjust Zxing scanner's focus area

Tags: ios, ipad, zxing

Currently the rectangle frame is almost take up the whole screen, may I know if there is anyway to reduce the focus area?

Because I found that if I use an iPhone app which has Zxing built in, in the iPad, the efficiency is better than the iPad app.

So I'm trying to reduce the focus area, hopefully this could yield me a better result in iPad.

Comment: Do you want to make the camera screen smaller?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about an iPad 3? The iPad 2 has a fixed-focus camera. There has recently been an issue detected with the iPad 3 support which led to poor decode rates, particularly for dense codes. It's been partially fixed by adjusting the resolution ZXing asks iOS for, but the fix isn't complete at this point.

Or are you just thinking about cropping down the region ZXing looks at to detect a code? This is unlikely to produce better decode rates. Given the resolution ZXing asks iOS for, it can scan an entire capture image very quickly. In theory, extraneous clutter could confuse it and cropping could reduce that, but I wouldn't spend any effort trying to improve the cropping until I was sure that confusion was really happening. I haven't seen any evidence of it.